# Android libgdx android.os.Bundle does not exist in NetBeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans, libgdx

I'm using NetBeans and I want to develop Android games using LibGDX. LibDGX works fine for Desktop but when I want to launch Android application, the line "import android.os.Bundle" is underlined and "package android.os does not exist" is written.
Could someone please help me ?
Thanks